# When asked to simplify a boolean logic statement, how to decide which factorization to apply first?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

Applying the wrong law can lead to the wrong simplification.
I may try de Morgan’s, when I should have applied the law of contradiction or distributivity law before applying de Morgan’s, and it can change from question to question.
Is there a method to choosing the right factorization?

Comment: When solving an algebraic equation like $3x+5=11$, how do you know whether to divide first or to subtract first?

Comment: I don't think that is the same?

Comment: In that example there is only one option to simplify, where in boolean logic there can be multiple laws that could be applied at each stage

Comment: They are exactly the same. There is more than one way to solve that algebraic expression. There is one obvious way that comes from experience. The same is true of boolean expressions.

Comment: What constraints are given on the form of the expression?  There are indeed expressions (even in DNF or CNF) that have more than one "simplest" equivalent form under very general definitions of simplicity, but it's difficult to give a precise answer without additional context.

Comment: It is just for complex logic statements with multiple simplification possibilities

Comment: @JohnDouma if that is the case, how do you choose the correct one with more complex algebra?

Comment: You learn by doing. The more problems you do the more experience you gain.

Comment: @JohnDouma So you should rely on intuition over reason to practice mathematical reduction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Karnaugh maps can be helpful for statements that are not too complicated.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map

Comment: Thanks for providing this, looks like it will help with the examples provided

Comment: @user1688726 Np. You can transfer statements from logical symbols to algebraic symbols via the following transformation: T =1, 0 = F, or = +, and = *, not A = $\bar A$, and $A \to B = \bar A + B$. It's been awhile since I've used this so I don't recall that it will show you what axioms to use to simplify the expression, but at the very least it will tell you what the simplest expression is so that you will  least know what you are working towards.